# how to make a column Unique based on comparing grouping id

Tags: c#, database, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I need to make sure that all View data for a specific Site element is unique, but I want to be able to reuse the value for other Site's with different id's.

**Example:**

*Site One*

- View one ref: ViewOne
- View two ref: ViewOne <-- error

*Site Two*

- View one ref: ViewOne <-- no error since it's a different site
- View two ref: ViewTwo

**View model:**

```
public class View : AssetsBase, IView
{
    public int SiteId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Ref { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<MetaEntry> MetaEntries { get; set; } = new HashSet<MetaEntry>();
    public virtual IEnumerable<HreflangEntry> HreflangEntries { get; set; } = new HashSet<HreflangEntry>();
}
```

**DB Context:**

```
builder.Entity<View>().ToTable("SiteView").HasIndex(sw => sw.Ref).IsUnique();
```

the current approach works as expected, but I'm limited to only use a Ref value once. is what I want possible?

Comment: you want like a composite index?  maybe you mean something like `HasIndex(sw => new {sw.Ref, sw.SiteId }).IsUnique();`,

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to user700390 who provided the solution.

DB Context:

```
builder.Entity<View>().ToTable("SiteView").HasIndex(sw => new { sw.Ref, sw.SiteId }).IsUnique();
```